# Cloudrun Resource readiness deadline exceeded or Deletion in progress

Tags: google-cloud-run

i find this error message in my log when i try to spin up a cloudrun instance with gcloud, terraform just keeps retrying until it times out.
`Initializing project for the current region. Resource readiness deadline exceeded or Deletion in progress. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.`

On the console it doesnt even show anything but an error icon.

When i create a cloudrun service directly from the artifact registry image by clicking deploy button. it creates the cloudrun service successfully but then i go back to the console for cloudrun and its still the error icon.

i used gcloud command to query the existing services and i get error as below
`ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'`

see my attachment for a screenshot of what the console looks like
[image]

Whenb i try to access the direct url of the cloudrun service in the browser i see the created service itself.
This url for example
`https://console.cloud.google.com/run/detail/YOUR-REGION/CLOUDRUN-SERVICE-NAME/revisions?project=PROJECT-NAME`

I tried it in all of europe region its all the same, us central1 worked but still didnt get my console interface to see the list of all services

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, can you check if this link on [troubleshooting Cloud Run issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) would help you out?